# calculate time differnece in hours and minutes using php when start time and end time is in 12 hour format

Tags: php

I'm working on hall reservation project and got stuck in calculating time difference in hours and minutes.

**Scenario:**
Start time = 11:00 AM.
End time = 03:30 PM.
Result = 04:30.

I have tried `$diff = $start->diff($end);`
but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should gmdate() function.

```
$StartTime= '11:00 AM';
$EndTime = '03:30 PM';
$sst = strtotime($StartTime);
$eet=  strtotime($EndTime);
$diff= $eet-$sst;
$timeElapsed= gmdate("h:i",$diff);
```

Comment: this is not reliable. it'll work fine for intervals less than 1 day, but if the difference stretches into multiple days, `h:i` **WILL** be wrong, since you're not including the day value.

Comment: yes, right..but the question is all about just time.. it did not include date.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) which is the best package (IMO) for handling dates and time in php